# Android - Canvas showing/hiding pictures with a countdown

Tags: android, canvas, countdown

I'm still new to Canvas. What I'm trying to do is to create a countdown that for every tick, will generate a random boolean. If it is true, show.png will show, else hide.png will show.

Basically, my game is Whack-A-Mole, I'm still trying this to a single mole. This is my code so far, I know it will not work and I'm still in my "experimenting" stage. How will I improve this? Without the countdown the canvas appears, but when I added the countdown and the "if appear=true/false", it doesn't work.

```
public class DrawingTheBall extends View{

    Bitmap show;
    Bitmap hide;
    int x;
    int y;

    public DrawingTheBall(Context context) {
        super(context);
        show = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.show);
        hide = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hide);
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        final Random aRandom = new Random();

        new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
             public void onTick(long msUntilFinished){

                 boolean appear = aRandom.nextBoolean();
                 if (appear){
                     Paint p = new Paint();
                     canvas.drawBitmap(show, x, y, p);
                 }else{
                     Paint p = new Paint();
                     canvas.drawBitmap(hide, x, y, p);
                 }
             }
             public void onFinish(){

             }
          }.start();

          invalidate();
    }

}
```

### -------------------

@user387184

Do I have to initialize the variables again? It says that the method myDrawRoutine(boolean) from the type MyCountDownTimer is never used locally. This is my new CountDownTimer.java:

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer{

    Bitmap show;
    Bitmap hide;
    int x;
    int y;
    Canvas canvas;

    public MyCountDownTimer(int millisInFuture, int countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private void myDrawRoutine(boolean appear) {
        if (appear){
            Paint p = new Paint();
            canvas.drawBitmap(show, x, y, p);
        }else{
            Paint p = new Paint();
            canvas.drawBitmap(hide, x, y, p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove all the code from your onDraw method except the super call and the if else. You wan't as little as possible in your onDraw method.

Comment: Where will I put the countdown?

Comment: leave the timer in the DrawingTheBall class as a field and create the timer in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

in your main code create and start the count down timer:

```
MyCountDownTimer counter = new MyCountDownTimer(30000,1000);

counter.start();
```

Then create the CountDownTimer class separately:

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer{

public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
...whatever you want to do when finished...
}

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
  boolean appear = aRandom.nextBoolean();
  myDrawRoutine(appear);
}
}

private void myDrawRoutine(boolean appear) {
  if (appear){
                 Paint p = new Paint();
                 canvas.drawBitmap(show, x, y, p);
             }else{
                 Paint p = new Paint();
                 canvas.drawBitmap(hide, x, y, p);
             }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW, there's something wrong in your object creation: MyCountDownTimer counter = new MyCount(30000,1000); Do I have to initialize the variables again in the Countdown class? beacuse I don't have any choice..

Comment: yes, I corrected that. What do you mean with "initialize variables again", which ones? If you are talking about p,x,y,show,hide? You could either pass these when creating the count down timer all the way through, or pass them when calling myDrawRoutine (getting them from whatever context you call it from). For example your paint could even be a final somewhere if you don't need to change it. That's up to you - its a matter of "clean" and "maintainable" design. Or do you mean anything else? PS you forgot to call myDrawRoutine from within the time onTick!

Comment: Yes, the p,x,y,show,hide.. :D Oh poop! I totally forgot to put it.. :) Thanks very much!